# Convert vertex label value of the jgraph to array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, vertex, jgraphx

Basically I have this code to print the cell label of each vertex I click of the jgraph. I am trying to store the values of the cells into a string array. I have tried this:

```
graphComponent.getGraphControl().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        ArrayList<Object> objarr = new ArrayList<Object>() ;  

                        if (e.getButton() == 3 && e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                        long x = e.getX();
                        long y = e.getY();
                        Object cell = graphComponent.getCellAt((int) x, (int)y); 
                        System.out.println(graph.convertValueToString(cell));
                        objarr.add(cell);
                    }

                        String[] stringArray = objarr.toArray(new String[100]) ;
}
                });         
    }
```

I get these errors when i try to click a vertex:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at GUIquery$2.mousePressed(GUIquery.java:498)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Every object has a `toString()` method. You should override this, if it doesn't already behave as you want, and call `cell.toString()`. Otherwise there should be a field for the label or method like `getLabel()` to access that field. Apart from that observation, it's very unclear where you are coming from with this question. For example variable `graphComponent` doesn't depend on this section of the code, only on `graph`. And you declared a local variable with `mxGraphComponent graphComponent` which blocks the scope of the outer `graphComponent` (the one `getGraphControl()` was called on)

Comment: You are right thanks. Dont know why they were left there. Removed them both. I tried storing the cell values clicked in the graph, into an array of strings, but it didnt work. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Well it's your graph...I can tell because it doesn't follow the naming convention for java classes. All you need to store a value into an array of Strings is a String. Following the debug prompts yourself and asking a well defined question are similar skills. Good luck.

Comment: Updated it. I hope that helps more. I tried to convert it to string array but I get the above errors

Comment: You still haven't said what a cell is!

Comment: override `String toString()` in class Vertex, or write and use `String vertexToString(vertex v){...}` Your convertvalue method isn't used right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37469/discussion-between-clwhisk-and-user2598911)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process to resolve such a problem.

```
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
at GUIquery$2.mousePressed(GUIquery.java:498)`
```

Line 498 must be

```
String[] stringArray = objarr.toArray(new String[100]) ;
```

Check [ArrayList documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`

When called this tries to store `ArrayList<Object>` members of type `Object` in a `String[]`. So it gave an [ArrayStoreException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html). The root of the problem is that the computer has no idea what **type** `cell` is. You declared is as an `Object`, so that's its type. If `getCellAt()` returns strings, use `String cell`.

As a note that is not an elegant solution here, if you had an `Object obj_str` that you knew was a `String`, you could cast it with

```
String str = (String)obj_str;
```